# Is there any way to duplicate widgets again after clearing screen in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm creating an app in kivy that has a few screens with some explanations. Each screen explains some steps about one certain concept. So instead of doing every explanation as it's own separate screen, I'm trying to combine the several explanations of each concept by clearing the widgets and then displaying new info on that screen. However, since I've cleared the past widgets, when I go back to the main menu screen and try to click on the original concept, all of the previous info is gone and only the last explanation is displayed so it doesn't let me go through the whole sequence again and see past explanations.

(code below)

so instead of making T1button and T2button into 2 separate screens, I'm clearing the widgets and then displaying the info and then repeating. Once I'm at T2button, I click to go "Back to Main Menu". Then, once I'm at the main menu, if I click to go see Intro(screen) again, then immediately the only things I see displayed are what's in T2button, so I can't see 1st or 2nd explanations (because I've cleared those widgets).

(short version: from the main menu I click and get to the intro screen, then I click "next page" and see new info displayed, then I click "next page" and see more new info displayed. then what i'm trying to do is go back to the main menu and go into the intro screen again to see the 1st or 2nd explanations but I can't, I am only able to see the last explanation)

```
class Intro(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='intro', font_size=45, halign='center'))
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='1st explanation goes here'))
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.T1 = Button(text='Next Page', background_color = purple, size_hint = (1,.5))
        self.T1.bind(on_press=self.T1button)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.T1)

    def T1button(self, instance):
        self.layout.clear_widgets()

        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='2nd title', font_size=45, halign='center'))
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='2nd explanation goes here...'))

        self.T2 = Button(text='Next Page', background_color = purple, size_hint = (1,.5))
        self.T2.bind(on_press=self.T2button)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.T2)

    def T2button(self, instance):
        self.layout.clear_widgets()

        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='last title', font_size=45, halign='center'))
        self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='last explanation goes here...'))
        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text='Back to Main Menu', size_hint = (1,.5), background_color = blue, on_press=self.menu))
        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text='Next', size_hint = (1,.5), background_color = purple, on_press=self.next_screen))
        self.add_widget(self.h_layout)

    def next_screen(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = 'concept2'
    def menu(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = 'main_menu'
```

So, I'm wondering if there's any way I could do it so that I can go back and see the first explanation without making it it's own screen? Like, after clearing the widgets is there a way to revive them so as to avoid making each explanation a separate screen (I don't want to put all of the explanations on the same screen altogether)

Disclaimer - I am not using a .kv file, it's all in python.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to kivy and OOP in python.